# How to get the observable collection of last selected tab using rad tab control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a tab control which carries 3 tabs. Each tab is bound to a different view model. Two view models are returning the ObservableCollection. I have a requirement to notify the user to save the changes if he has made any while going to the another tab. Now on the Selection Changed event of tab control i am trying to check if any changes have been made on last selected tab but collection is always coming null. Is there any way or any event that could help me with this scenario?

I tried converting the tab control to rad tab control and there i found an event PreviewSelectionChanged. I don't know if that could help me with this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PreviewSelectionChanged` is a [Tunneling Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) so this should give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how ?

Comment: PreviewSelectionChanged tunnels to root. When PreviewSelectionChanged  event is fired the View is still not closed and you have your ViewModel still loaded and then you can check if it is dirty (something is changed) show message box.

Comment: Yes got it done but not with the help of isdirty :). I am checking the HasChanges property which return me true if any changes has been made.